# In the following sentence, why "slowly ate" fit the replacement test but is not considered a proper constituent

Tags: syntax

> She slowly ate a donut,

Where I was told that *slowly ate a donut* was a constituency, and *ate a donut* was a constituent,BUT *slowly ate* was not, since they are not under the same node...

Which all make sense, but it doesn't chime with concept of constituency test I learned earlier when it is said that

in the sentence

> The angey boss fired me

the angry boss is a constituent because it can be replaced by a single word: boss, angry boss is also a constituent because it can be replaced by another word(boss) etc.

​

Thank you for your time in advance.

Comment: In ‘the angry boss fired me’, _the angry boss_ cannot be replaced by the single word _boss_, at least not in most varieties of English. It can be replaced with _he_, but _boss_ on its own is not valid as a noun phrase with no determiner to mark definiteness. _Angry boss_ can be replaced by _boss_, leaving the valid _the boss_. Also, why are you asking about Reddit posts? This isn’t Reddit.

Comment: the boss fired me make sense, no? Also, sorry, I copypaste my post from reddit...

Comment: Yes, ‘the boss fired me’ makes sense, but that’s substituting _angry boss_ with the single word _boss_. It’s not substituting _the angry boss_ with the single word _boss_. If you substitute _the angry boss_ for the single word _boss_, the result is ‘boss fired me’, which is not valid to most speakers. (_Boss_ is used in this sort of pseudo-pronominal way in slang in some lects, but most people would find it ungrammatical.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general you should always use multiple constituency tests, because some are too general and others too specific. In this case, we can also use coordination (*The angry boss and the mean supervisor fired me*), clefting (*It is the angry boss who fired me*), pseudoclefting (*The angry boss is who fired me*), passivization (*I was fired by the angry boss*), and answer fragments (*Who fired you? — The angry boss*), probably among others.

The replacement test is best done with proforms: pronouns or empty verbs like *do so/it*. This is called [proform substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constituent_(linguistics)#Proform_substitution_(replacement)). We cannot easily replace *angry boss* with a pronoun, because of the definite article *The*. What you are doing is [general subtitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constituent_(linguistics)#General_substitution); the linked Wikipedia page gives various examples in which this test fails.

The proform substitution test is more reliable, and fails with *slowly ate*. This test can be used to show that *slowly ate a donut* is a constituent (*(John slowly ate a donut, and) she did so too*), but this fails with *slowly ate* (**John slowly ate a donut, and she did so a bagel*).

There are other tests that you can apply as well. For example, answer fragments: you can have *What did she do? — Slowly eat a donut* but not **What did she do a donut? — Slowly eat*: you would have to add *to (the donut)* to the question and *it* to the answer. On the other hand you can have again *What did she do slowly? — Eat a donut*, so *ate a donut* is a constituent.

What you are actually doing when you replace *slowly ate* with *ate* is testing the [omission](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constituent_(linguistics)#Omission_(deletion)) of *slowly*. This test works especially well for adverbs and adverbial phrases, and correctly suggests that *slowly* is a constituent.